# PHP observer pattern (push strategy)

Tags: php, oop

I need to implement an observer design pattern in PHP. The problem with the standard **SplObserver** interface is that its **update(SplSubject $subject)** method doesn't support supplying additional arguments which is necessary for me.

Do I have to create my own interface like this?

```
interface PushObserver {
  public function update($sender, array $pushData);
}
```

Or is there a more standard way which wouldn't require users of my class to implement my own interface? I know I am not the only one dealing with this, but I haven't found a single article about this issue.

Comment: Without seeing the original code, could you not override the original method?

Comment: What about public members on the sender that the observers could use for additional info?

Comment: @Ben Can you be more concrete? I kinda don't know how I can override method in SplObserver in any nice way.

Comment: @Pinetree Thats the origin of my problem that I don't have these public members. I want to catch events on methods like insert(), update(), delete() and I need to pass data about how the request went.

Comment: Well, if you need just transient info which should not be a member of the sender, then I think you have no choice but using "non standard" custom classes. Having said that, I do not think there's anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's really important to you to demand `$pushData` in your observer, but if it's only optional you can still implement or extend `SplObserver`, but make the `$pushData` optional, it lets you do that:

```
class PushObserver implements SplObserver {
    public function update (SplSubject $SplSubject, Array $pushData = null) {}
}
```

Or:

```
interface PushObserver extends SplObserver {
    public function update (SplSubject $SplSubject, Array $pushData = null);
}
```

Comment: I think PHP will complain if the update function does not have the same signature as the one in the SplObserver, but I can't remember if it's an error or just a warning.

Comment: I did test it out in PHP 5.4.3 before I posted this. PHP doesn't mind as long as additional arguments are only optional - 'cos the old signature will still work.

Comment: The problem here is that if I accessed instances of this class by interface (which I want). I wouldn't see the overloaded version.

Comment: @HonzaBrabec true, but does that matter? It still has an interface, and anyone who cares to look can see that your interface extends SplObserver... why is it important that it directly extend SplObserver? This pattern seems to be pretty neat OO practice to me.

Comment: @RobinWinslow I did not know this about optional params. This will be useful.

Comment: OK looks like I have 2 choices. This one or the getPushData() method mentioned in the other answer. I personally prefer this one because the other one would pollute the public interface of my class with a method that IMO doesn't fit there. I will accept this answer if nothing else comes in a while

Comment: @HonzaBrabec I think you worry too much about not using "the standard interface". That is there to provide basic functionality, which is obviously not enough in you case, so the need to extend it is valid and you should do it.

Comment: Looks like I have to get rid of the type-hint SplSubject on the interface. That would require me to implement SplSubject which I am not able to do because I wont attach SplObservers but PushObservers (which is kinda bad name, have to figure out something better).

Comment: If your push subjects are supersets of SplSubjects then you could once again extend SplSubject with your own interface. Otherwise, you genuinely have a different interface and I guess you'll have to just abandon SPL and invent your own.

Answer (score 1):

The sender knows about the pushData, right? Why bother creating a new interfaces if editing the sender could be enough?

Just add a getPushData() method to $sender to retrieve that variable.

Comment: This is a solution too, although I prefer the other one as stated in the comment below it. Anyway I gave you +1 for your effort

Answer (score 1):

In your `SplObserver`, modify your `update` method to reflect:

```
public function update(SplSubject $subject, array $params = array())
```

and then use `call_user_func_array` to do the rest.